# In a strongly-typed world, why isn't ASP.NET MVC's fragile dependency on naming conventions frowned upon?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, programming-languages

Since forever, strongly-typed objects have been a foundation of object-oriented programming. Fast-forward to 5 minutes ago, when working with the Entity Framework and MVC3, I was forced to add this to my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="_MY_EXACT_CLASS_NAME_DbContext" connectionString="Data Source=blahblah.../>
</connectionStrings>
```

Great, My entire application depends on an arbitrarily-chosen name in an XML attribute. Is this really what modern programming looks like? Misspelling a class name is a serious offense, one the compiler leads us directly into fixing, but in this case, I'll just get a runtime exception message. If Mr. aforementioned exception message in a good mood, he'll point me toward Mordor, and I'll trudge off toward another Mount Doom of wasted debugging hours to destroy the invisible One-Typo-To-Rule-Them-All.

The same goes for Controllers:

```
routes.MapRoute("BE_CAREFUL","{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "ONE_FALSE_MOVE_AND",
            action = "BUT_I_SWEAR_IT_SAID_BUILD_SUCCEEDED" }
);
```

It seems like things come and go in waves. Strongly-typed objects had their day in the sun, and now we're all girl-next-door over the anonymous "var". I'll admit, being coy about your type stirs up a lot of sexy scenarios - especially knowing you don't have to do any setup work -  but here's The Actual Question:

**How do the forefathers of object-oriented programming feel about our "advancement" of their art by adding a bunch of wishy-washy, do-sorta-whatever anonymous constructs while at the same time creating fragile dependencies on naming conventions?**

For all we know, MVC4 might suddenly require that all names be preceded by exactly 4.7 spaces followed by lolcat ASCII art. Why? Because yes, that's why. Take a moment and marvel at the fact that you just witnessed the birth of a naming convention. Obviously, this is seriously solid foundational material for a flagship framework.

So, if there's one thing I want my entire codebase to both functionally and philosophically depend on, there's nothing more mission-critical to the mathematic logic of programming than..... Microsoft's® English-Language Naming Conventions!

```
</sarcasm>
</griping>

<!-- resume enjoying all of MVC's amazing features, after eating any humble pie served up in the comments -->
```

Comment: very subjective. Also, the naming conventions are probably more related to Rails and Django than MS. Finally, `var` is strongly (and statically) typed, and for the other "strong type" arguments you are making, static typing is the type system you are actually interested in

Comment: I'm just gonna upvote because it's a well worded rant.

Comment: I'd rather have a plain text config file than some compiled config file you seem to be looking for. I agree on the default routing though.

Comment: Real Programmers Don't Use Pascal

Comment: "How do the forefathers of object-oriented programming feel"...are you expecting them to hop on Stack Overflow to answer this?

Comment: @Michael no doubt that was his exact expectation.

Comment: I was hoping at least one of the Gang of Four might drop by. I mean, there's four of them, right?

Comment: Some of those *forefathers of OOP* created CLOS and Smalltalk---not statically typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My entire application depends on an arbitrarily-chosen name in an XML attribute.

This is called "coding by convention" or "convention over configuration" ... you pick a few things that need configuration, and then everything else just "falls into place". Like using razor and having _layout.cshtml in /views/shared. Or like using razor and having `mySpecialController` with `ActionResult Index` and `/views/mySpecial/Index.cshtml` ... those are just a way of letting the convention work for you.

> Since forever, strongly-typed objects have been a foundation of object-oriented programming.
>   Strongly-typed objects had their day in the sun, and now we're all girl-next-door over the anonymous "var".

var variables are just a shorthand to make things slightly more readable, the compiler still strongly and statically types things at compile time. Consider the difference here:

```
foreach (var c in Customers) { /* do stuff */ }
foreach (CustomerDataItem customerDataItem in Customers) { /* do stuff */ }
```

As you can see, the first one says "get a item c from Customers" and the second one says the same thing but good lord man I've already written two more lines of code while you're still typing the long one. Granted, with ReSharper that advantage disappears, however ...

> For all we know, MVC4 might suddenly require that all names be preceded by exactly 4.7 spaces followed by lolcat ASCII art. Why? Because yes, that's why.

har.

> How do the forefathers of object-oriented programming feel about our "advancement" of their art by adding a bunch of wishy-washy, do-sorta-whatever anonymous constructs while at the same time creating fragile dependencies on naming conventions?

Ok, so this was mostly just frustration, but I'll bite. The guys that started wanted simpler code (BASIC, COBOL look up what those mean) and so they want things to be easier and more math-y. That's where things are moving (LINQ is set math, and higher order calculus; also see F# and Python)

So they would LOVE what we're doing now. Getting away from procedural code (algebra) and moving into set-oriented logic (adv calculus). Also see Event Handlers `;-)`

---

So .. having said all that: I've been in your shoes. I've asked those questions. I've studied at the feet of masters. I love where the languages are going.

In your next life, I want you to learn node.js. I want you to learn async evented processing, and I want you to understand how things don't rely on ANSI-C anymore. We've made a lot of progress in this industry, and things are looking up. Things are looking up every day. I love where we are, and I think it's the right thing for our industry.

Cheers, and HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the info, lots of good stuff to dig into. Node.js has been on my "someday" list for far too long. I have no clue what async evented processing is, but it sounds awesome and I'm jealous that you get to use it in actual conversation.

Comment: Absolutely. Find someone's feet to study at. Learn from them. Move up the ladder and stand on the shoulders of giants. It's the only way.

Comment: Say, what does "HTH" stand for? I've been on SO for all of a single day, so I didn't know if that was some insider acronym ya'll have.

Comment: Hope this helps. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_slang It belongs to the internet, not StackOverflow or StackExchange. It's been around for about 20 years now ... probably a lot longer.

Comment: Good to know. I always thought that phrase was Scott Guthrie's trademark sign-off, and I was ripping him off with blatant disregard for proper attribution.

Answer (score 0):

My answer: "because of the advancements in automated testing".